# Can I run exodus wallet on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: bitcoin

I download it directly from the Exodus website but I can't run the software by double clicking or directly from the terminal

Comment: what is name of downloaded file

Comment: Exodus-linux-x64-1.26.2.zip

Comment: A .zip indicates an archive, a compressed set of file(s).  You will need to expand the archive, and see what's in it to determine how to install the program.  Please look at [this long question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu) to see installation methods for various types of files.  Archive extraction can be done by right-clicking on the file, in the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website, the [Exodus wallet](https://www.exodus.io/releases/) for Linux downloads as a zip archive containing a binary file.

Here is how you can download/install Version 1.27.2:

```
$ wget https://exodusbin.azureedge.net/releases/Exodus-linux-x64-1.27.2.zip
$ unzip Exodus-linux-x64-1.27.2.zip 
$ exodus-1.27.2/Exodus-linux-x64/Exodus
```

And Exodus now installs!

Comment: Thank you so much, but still doesn't run

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: cannot find or open Exodus-linux-x64-1.27.2.zip, Exodus-linux-x64-1.27.2.zip.zip or Exodus-linux-x64-1.27.2.zip.ZIP.

Comment: Are you in the directory you downloaded it to? Or did you follow my steps?

Comment: follow your steps